# SVG path - exclude overlapping shapes directly from code

Tags: css, svg, vector-graphics

My SVG image is a schema of Switzerland flag. The cross in the middle is made by two rectangle paths. Those paths overlaps themselves. I want to remove two vertical lines in the middle of the cross in order to make it consistent with the real flag schema.

Is there any way to edit the code in order to wipe off those lines?

```
<g fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="1pt">
<path  stroke="white" stroke-width="1" fill="black" d="M0 0h640v480H0z"/>
<g fill="black">
  <path stroke="white" stroke-width="1" d="M170 194.997h299.996v89.997H170z"/>
  <path stroke="white" stroke-width="1" d="M275 89.997h89.996v299.996H275z"/>
</g>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zoLdduxa/2/

Answer (score 2):

It can be less complicated:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="640" height="480">
  <path fill="#fff" d="M1 1h640v480H1z"/>
  <path stroke="red" stroke-width="100" d="M320 50v380M130 240h380"/>
</svg>
```

Suggest learning here: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html

And do some magic here: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

**Update:**
Single path cross

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="640" height="480">
  <path stroke="#fff" d="M0 0h640v480H1V0z"/>
  <path stroke="#fff" d="M270 90h100v100h100v100H370v100H270V290H170V190h100V90z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think I cannot do it this way. If I understood correctly you've changed those two paths into one path with huge stroke. But I need to keep  the schema with black background and white borders separating space outside and inside cross (just like on my jsfiddle).

Comment: Maybe If it impossible to combine those two paths into one without overlapping lines directly from the code I can import svg file to some program like Adobe and change it there?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted the flag )). Obviously you can make the cross in one path.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat your first line with stroke-width="0", after you draw second shape.  It is not pretty, but that should work.

```
    <path stroke="black" stroke-width="0" d="M170 194.997h299.996v89.997H170z"/>
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="640" height="480">
<g fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="1pt">
<path  stroke="white" stroke-width="1" fill="black" d="M0 0h640v480H0z"/>
<g fill="black">
<path stroke="white" stroke-width="1" d="M170 194.997h299.996v89.997H170z"/>
<path stroke="white" stroke-width="1" d="M275 89.997h89.996v299.996H275z"/>
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="0" d="M170 194.997h299.996v89.997H170z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```